# Is it okay to use multi-cable staples/hangers on a running board for NM wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring, basement, code-compliance

As part of a basement project, I am trying to tidy up the previous homeowner's electrical work.  One thing I have encountered is a number of NM cables run perpendicular to joists and stapled directly to them.  I know that this isn't code, and that when cables run perpendicular they must be through bored holes in joists or on running boards.

My question: **is it legit to attach the cables to running boards with multi-cable staples/hangers?**  I tidied up a couple of feet of run to see how it worked/looked.  (see photos below)

From my reading of the "334.15(C) In Unfinished Basements and Crawl Spaces" this would seem to be allowed, as the cables are indeed *on running boards*.  However, each cable is not stapled individually to the running board...so perhaps some inspectors would have trouble with this?

FWIW, I am using the [Gardner Bender Multi-cable staple](https://www.gardnerbender.com/en/p/MCS-20W/SnapSHOT-Multi-Cable-Staple-Red-NM)

Also a related question (let me know if I should break it into a new thread): **how wide must a running board be in the case of these multi-cable staples?**  In the photos below I am using a 2.5" piece of strapping, but I wonder if I need to have it wide enough so that I have the required 1.25" clearance from the edge that joists need...?

Here are two photos.  Note that there are currently 4 NM cables in the hangers - these were pre-existing and I need to add three more.  Seven total seemed like a lot stapled side-by-side on a running board, and the hangers seem a good solution unless...they aren't?

[image: side view of cables secured by multi-cable hangars]

And here is the view from underneath
[image: bottom view of cables secured by multi-cable hangars]

Comment: The generally repeated explanation for that code section is to prevent people from hanging things from electrical cabling. The thought being if it's stapled flat to the running board that it will be less tempting to hang things on. In that way your implementation seems against the intention of the code but somebody else who knows code much better than me will likely be along soon!

Comment: Thanks, @Matthew.  I have indeed seen the "prevent hanging things" as motivation for the running boards.  I would say that with these multi-cable holders there is actually less free space around the cables and temptation to hang something from them than if they were run through a hole bored through the center of the joist, which as we know is perfectly acceptable.  Certainly, that's just my own opinion and it'll ultimately be up to a particular inspector's judgement...maybe if I used cable ties to snug everything up between each joist that would help with reducing hanging temptation

Comment: Small cables do need a support when perpendicular to the joists larger cables do not require a backing board. You can use the clips as they are a listed device. How many wires are bundled in that 1 slot?  That is not allowed. Each cable goes in a slot.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @EdBeal.  Those clips state that they can hold up to eight 12-gauge cables.  They have 4 slots, so I believe each slot can hold two cables.

Comment: Susie, I rarely use them some inspectors do not like them , 2 cables under a clip or staple is code so if the mfg allows 2 per slot and listed it would be ok.